# Unable to update modern "Image" list item field using CSOM SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom, pnp-core-sdk, pnp-framework

I am using CSOM API to update fields in a SharePoint list. I can update all fields fine, I just can't update or add to the "Image" Field. This is a new field type added in late 2020, separate from the "Hyperlink/Picture" field type. I see in the List settings, it is marked as "Thumbnail".

I have tried to set the image column to a url, as you can do this for the previous "Hyperlink/Picture" field type. Is there a way to update this field using CSOM? I can't find any mention of this new Image field type in any of the documentation.

```
ListItemCreationInformation itmCreation = new ListItemCreationInformation();
newItem = myList.AddItem(itmCreation);

string imageUrl = "www.myImage.com"
newItem["IMAGECOLUMN"] = imageUrl ;

newItem.Update();
cc.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Try to create image list item field in sharepoint, add an image. Then use csom and get list item details and check how the link to the image is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern "Image" Field is expecting a JSON formatted object.
I created an Image class, serialized it and then sent it that way:

```
Entities.Image imgg = new Entities.Image
{
  fileName = "img.jpg",
  serverUrl = "https://site.sharepoint.com",
  serverRelativeUrl = "/sites/mySite/Shared%20Documents/New Images Upload/img.jpg"
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(imgg, Formatting.Indented);

ListItemCreationInformation itmCreation = new ListItemCreationInformation();
newItem = myList.AddItem(itmCreation);
newItem["imageColumninternalName"] = json;
newItem.Update();
cc.ExecuteQuery();
```

And it worked, strange I couldn't find any documentation on this.